# Solving an exercise on groups with universal properties

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

In the book Algebra: Chapter 0, the author asks the following problem.

Let $G$ be a group, $H\trianglelefteq G$ and $N$ is subgroup of $G$ with $H\subseteq N$.

> ([Exer. 8.11, p. 107](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=deWkZWYbyHQC&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=exercise%208.11%20Algebra%20Chapter%200%20without%20invoking%20universal&source=bl&ots=ZeTTCGsu9Q&sig=fnpIEivKieS6DHSwdQGpIGojwIs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYyN-XrZnRAhVMt48KHSyZCIcQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=exercise%208.11%20Algebra%20Chapter%200%20without%20invoking%20universal&f=false)) Prove by hand (i.e. without invoking universal properties) that $N$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $N/H$ is normal in $G/H$.

I know how to do this; but my question is other side of the problem.

***Invoking universal properties, how can we prove this?***

Comment: Normally you would "prove" this hands-down and shouting "correspondence theorem". So what is the definition of a universal property in this context?

Comment: Sorry! I don't have idea of it. I looked into the problem and immediately came ti question - why author want to avoid that way? I mean how can we do that way which author don't expect?

Comment: This is precisely (the proof of) Proposition 8.10 of your book.

Comment: Oh, is it so? I was just doing exercises of it.

Comment: Browsing through the book I see some theorems that are more at the level of Category Theory (if you are familiar with it), which abstracts groups and homomorphisms, and aims at more universal properties also valid for Rings and Fields for example.